# Google map as fixed background like on foursquare

Tags: html, css, google-maps, foursquare

I'm trying to do something like [this](https://foursquare.com/explore?cat=topPicks&near=Saint%20Petersburg,%20RU). I want to have google map as a fixed background and place my content(some text) on it as it's made on foursquare. Also i want to be able to scroll my content. This is my [effort](http://jsfiddle.net/X5r8r/918/):

```
#map
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}
#content
{
    width: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 4px solid black;
}
​
```

But the map disappears. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by static? image?

Comment: I've read about it. No, i will dynamically load markers on this map.

Comment: You can try: http://nickbalestra.tumblr.com/post/9167355389/using-custom-markers-with-google-static-map-apis

Comment: Thanks, but i need dynamic map.)

Comment: Just position the map wrapper fixed width 100% width and height. In this wrapper you put your content wrapper in an absolute position and set the overflow to auto to have it scrollable.

Comment: Like this or i got you wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/X5r8r/920/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a way you can do it: http://jsfiddle.net/X5r8r/927/

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}

#map-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}

#map
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#content
{
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    border: 4px solid black;
    background:#fff;
    padding:20px;
}
```

Comment: Thans, but when i scroll down your map seems not to be fixed. I need map to react like here: https://foursquare.com/explore?cat=topPicks&near=Saint%20Petersburg%2C%20RU

Comment: Yes, this is it! Thanks, man) Correct your answer and i'll accept it.

Comment: Oh, sorry, i was in hurry to accept your answer. In your solution you used static map, but i need dynamic. Here is your code with dynamic map: http://jsfiddle.net/X5r8r/925/ unfortunately the same problem. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: For the record: here is the API documentation for generating those images: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps